# Bibtex wrong pages position

Tags: bibtex

test.bib :

```
@book{PProof,
    author = {Garey Michael, Johnson David},
    title   = {Computers and Intractability; A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness},
    year    = {1979},
    publisher = {W H Freeman {\&} Co},
    pages = {96 -- 105},
}
```

test.tex :

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,reqno,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}     % ams stuff should be before font loading
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % should be after font loading
\usepackage{fixltx2e,babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}    % bibtex package


\bibliographystyle{natdin}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

output:

GAREY MICHAEL, Johnson D.: Computers and Intractability; A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness. W H Freeman & Co, 1979. – 96 – 105 S.

Why is here the number of the pages bevor S. ?

How can i fix this? is there something missing?

Comment: First of all, how should we know? You are not giving us any information as to which style you are using. Please extend your example with a minimal LaTeX document that is compilable and is using the data you provide.

Comment: i made an update.

Comment: (1) use `pages = {96-105}`, (2) the `S` seems intentional if one looks through `natdin.bst` looking for the formatting associated with `pages`, no idea why it is used.

Comment: Plus my German is not good enough to understand the comments at the top of `natdin.bst`.

Comment: S. stand for Seite the german word for pages. but i wonder why the number is before the word

Comment: The item you're citing is a book, so `pages` can only refer to the total number of pages and that's why `natdin` puts “S.” after the number. A place in a book should be specified at the citation in the document, not in the bibliography.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are three issues with your bibliographic entry. Ordered from least serious to most serious, they are:

- The `pages` field should be given as

  ```
  pages = {96-105},
  ```

  Stating the field as `pages = {96--105},` would be OK too.
- In BibTeX's syntax, authors must be separated with the keyword `and`, *not* with commas. Thus, the `author` field should be stated either as

  ```
  author = {Michael R. Garey and David S. Johnson},
  ```

  or, if you prefer to state the surname ahead of the given names, as

  ```
  author = {Garey, Michael R. and Johnson, David S.},
  ```
- It's not common practice to provide a `pages` field for entries of type `@book`. I believe that what you need is a *different* entry type, viz., `@incollection`.

Sure enough, with these changes made, the `S.` label is placed *before* the page range:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,reqno,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@incollection{PProof,
    author = {Michael R. Garey and David S. Johnson},
    title   = {Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness},
    year    = {1979},
    publisher = {W\,H Freeman~\& Co},
    pages = {96-105},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{fixltx2e,babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}    
\bibliographystyle{natdin}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The item is a book, not a collection of articles.

Comment: @egreg - The `@incollection` entry type is quite flexible, and it can be used for more than just collections of articles or essays. Because the OP wants to provide a non-blank `pages` field for the entry in question, bibtex and `natdin` have to given some "help" if the contents of the `pages` field are to be displayed correctly. For the `natdin` style, it turns out that the `@incollection` entry type generates a correctly formatted entry, whereas the type `@book` does not.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

[Egreg’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224266/bibtex-wrong-pages-position#comment526869_224266) to specify the pages at citation should usually be the way to go.

For this, you would remove the `pages` field from the `@book` entry and use `\cite[96--105]{PProof}` in your document. The pages will appear with the citation in the text, but not in the bibliographic entry of the book at the end of your document.

#### Option 2

If you insist on displaying the pages in the bibliographic entry, you should go with [Mico’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224288/44278).

However, I would make an addition:

If you want multiple citations to the same book, each referring to different pages, chapters, or similar, and each appearing as an individual entry in your bibliography, you could place all static information in a `@Book` entry and create `@InBook` entries for all your specific sub-citations. You then cite those `@InBook` entries.

<sub>Note, that I use `@inbook` and not `@incollection` for the sub-citations, because – according to the Bibtex documentation – `@incollection` should be used for “*a part of a book having its own title*” with `title` **and** `booktitle` as required fields, thus causing warnings/problems, if only one `title` field is given.</sub>

```
@inbook{PProofcaseA,
crossref = {PProof},
pages = {96--105},
}

@inbook{PProofcaseB,
crossref = {PProof},
pages = {222--700},
}

@book{PProof,
author = {Garey Michael and Johnson David},
title   = {Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness},
year    = {1979},
publisher = {W\,H Freeman~\& Co},
}
```

Note, that the master-entry has to be placed *after* the sub-entries for the cross-referencing to work.

This approach has the advantage that you only have to enter the static information once.
Furthermore, styles can group all those entries, create an entry for the book itself and link all individual entries to it within the bibliography, etc.

This approach can also be used if you want to give any other information specific to the cited subpart (if the corresponding field is accepted by the style-file).